# How to get a dependent drop down list and other as free text option?

Tags: selectlist

I got a request to have 2 pick lists, with dependancy (that's easy to implement) but the request is to have in the controlling field: the option of: 'Other'

When selecting Other - the value needs to come from a free text box.

I guess I can do it with some Field Updates and a 3rd field that gets populated from the drop down, whenever the controlling field is NOT 'Other' but that's gonna be an over kill.

I know it's not possible with standard behavior, but can it be done in VF?

Answer (score 2):

Here is something that can be done with Visualforce, but it still requires more fields.

1. Have your normal controllring picklist, Controlling
2. Have your normal dependent picklist, Dependent
3. Create a text field called, Dependent Other
4. Create a formula field called Dependent Value.  The formula field should use an IF to evaulate to the value of the text field if the controlling picklist value is 'Other', otherwise it should evaluate to the value of the Dependent picklist. This is the value to use everywhere else in the system as the actual recorded value.

From a UI perspective when the user selects 'Other' from the controlling picklist, reRender that part of the page with the dependent picklist not shown and instead a text input for the Dependent Other text field.